# usb_cam don't work,can'tsee any image

Tags: ros, usb-cam, image, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when I use usb_cam, I did this: `roscore` and `rosrun usb_cam usb_cam_node`.
I also used `rosparam set usb_cam/pixel_format yuyv` and I received:

```
           usb_cam video_device set to [/dev/video0]
           usb_cam io_method set to [mmap]
           usb_cam image_width set to [640]
           usb_cam image_height set to [480]
           usb_cam pixel_format set to [yuyv]
           usb_cam auto_focus set to [0]
          1 frames/sec at 1353855178.185472348
          1 frames/sec at 1353855178.314173063
          4 frames/sec at 1353855178.849589157
          7 frames/sec at 1353855179.782349046
```

but I can't see image on my screen,and roswtf showed that :

```
Loaded plugin tf.tfwtf
No package or stack in context
================================================================================
Static checks summary:
No errors or warnings
================================================================================
Beginning tests of your ROS graph. These may take awhile...
analyzing graph...
... done analyzing graph
running graph rules...
... done running graph rules

Online checks summary:

Found 3 error(s).

ERROR Communication with [/rosout] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/usb_cam] raised an error: 
ERROR The following nodes should be connected but aren't:
 * /usb_cam->/rosout (/rosout)
```

I am new to ROS. Please help me! Thank a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49062/usb_cam-don%27t-work,can%27tsee-any-image/) by [Allen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3667/allen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-11-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-11-26**:
What command are you using to display the images? What does `rostopic list` show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For webcams, I recommend you to use gscam instead of usb_cam

http://www.ros.org/wiki/gscam

---

Originally posted by [BeLioN](https://answers.ros.org/users/2449/belion/) with karma: 126 on 2012-11-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0